# How to use non-capturing groups in this example

Tags: regex

The following regex:

```
(\d+\.?\d+?)px \/\* (\d+) \*\/
```

matches `5.5px /* 1440 */` in:

```
position: relative;
padding: 5.5px /* 1440 */ 9px /* 1440 */;
border: 0;
```

but not `9px /* 1440 */`.

---

This regex does match both `5.5px /* 1440 */` and `9px /* 1440 */` but captures groups I do not wish to capture.

```
(\d+(\.)?(\d+)?)px \/\* (\d+) \*\/
```

---

How can I write `(\d+(\.)?(\d+)?)px \/\* (\d+) \*\/` without capturing `(\.)` and `(\d+)`?

Comment: You want `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)px \/\* (\d+) \*\/`. Your regex is saying "match any digit one or more times, followed by a possible `.`, followed by one or more, but as few as possible digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

As per my original comment...

Your regex is saying:

- `\d+` Match any digit one or more times
- `\.?` Match the dot character `.` literally zero or one time
- `\d+?` Match one or more digits, but as few as possible (lazy quantifier).

Realistically, the error is on the last line and changing `+?` to `*` should fix your issue, however, the following approach is usually regarded as the better method to catching decimal point numbers as it doesn't allow your regex to catch numbers ending in decimal points without number following it (i.e. `10.` - this will be matched by `\d+\.?\d*`, but it will not be matched by `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`)

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/oLRn2u/1)

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)px \/\* (\d+) \*\/
```

The regex above uses `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

---

### Explanation

- `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Match the following zero or one time

  - `\.` Match the dot character `.` literally
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits

Comment: Whoever said `100.` is an invalid syntax? It shows significant figures for trailing zeroes.

Comment: @StephenLeppik no one, I never said it's wrong, I'm simply showing the OP what could potentially happen if they use the other method of `\.?\d*`. I've seen this many times in regex question on stackoverflow where people wonder why `10.` is being caught when it shouldn't. Again, it's the user's choice whether to use the method that allows trailing `.`, or prevents trailing `.`

Answer (score 2):

`\d+?` is a lazy version of `\d+`, NOT an optional `\d+`.

Instead, the `*` quantifier means 0 or more.

You can also use the `(?:…)` non-capture syntax.